# 2 washing machines of the same make, standing water in both

Tags: washing-machine

So basically, around 2 months ago I got a new washing machine. The first washing machine I had was not draining properly and was getting old, so I got a new Beko WTK82011W 8KG one.

I did a wash cycle and it was not draining at all. I figured that it was faulty because everything was connected properly from what I could see, and the filter was fine.

So I replaced it and got the same make and this one still has some standing water in it after a wash cycle. Now I'm wondering what is wrong with it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It directly connects to the sink drain. It's plugged into the wall. The water pipe is fine, water is getting in.

Comment: Could be a defective batch of machines, or something wrong with the plumbing.  Does the drain fit loose in the drain pipe, or is it sealed up?  If loose then a plumbing problem leave water on the floor, so defective machines.  Would return and try another make.  Re-read the instructions to see if everything is right.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand well, when you say the drain fit loose into the drain pipe, do you mean on the back of the machine?

Comment: What @crip659 is saying, your drain might be clogged. Also make sure the washing machine drain hose is not sitting to tight in the drain hole, it must be loose fit.

Comment: @Ruskes I don't think the drain is clogged since my sink drains fine and I checked before, and it was empty
I untightened the drain hole a bit, so its somewhat secure but not tight into it at all. I hope this works

Comment: You've had 3 washing machines (2 of them brand new) "failed" because they're not draining properly. At this point, it's time to stop blaming the expensive hardware and take a look at the plumbing. A picture of your laundry room, specifically of where the washer drains into the house plumbing would be helpful (you can [edit] the picture into your question). It does sound likely that there's a clog somewhere between where the washer drains and whatever sink you're referring to drains.

Comment: I didn't blame the hardware, I'm trying to trouble shoot as I am wondering what is wrong... No need to be so aggressive about it
And there is no clog. I am serious.

Comment: Seems like very long part of hose is above machine's drain orifice. When internal pump stops, all water that resided in hose flows down into machine. It can also suck some water from the sink or pipe. You can try to temporarily insert the hose into some low drainage, like toilet.

Comment: I don't have anything that low I don't think (right now)
The toilet is on the other side of the flat. I'm not sure what to do

Comment: And as far as your issue is concerned... I'm wondering if that S pipe maybe has some mild obstructions in it. Does washing machine water sometimes bubble up in the sink?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to remove that hanging bend and the elevation behind the machine. It might make it difficult for the machine to get rid of its water. Try giving it a more or less straight path to the drain (so that it doesn't droop, or go higher than the washing machine itself) and do a test run. If you use any kinds of aid (stool, stack of buckets etc), keep in mind the machine shakes during centrifuge so they shouldn't lean against it. The easiest is probably to place the machine at a distance in front of the cabinet and plug the drain in.

Comment: Hi sorry, I have been busy recently and I haven't been able to reply. I've been trying to do a test run but it doesn't even seem like I'm able to get water into my washing machine now, I turn it on and nothing happens. No rotations or anything. I am from the UK. I think it is probably because of the downhill then uphill part of the pipe, though I am trying to find a solution around it since I don't have the tools to drill a big enough hole into the side of the cabinet where my drain is.

Comment: Does the door lock properly? This is a common cause of washing machines not running. Try giving it a gentle but firm extra push. Another thing could be it needs to be level (in both directions). I'd put a level on top and temporarily adjust the screws on the feet.

Comment: It does lock properly, chances are the load that I put in was too heavy because of the previous water. I took it out and it's now working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how much water is left in the machine after it's done running, but I would suggest that the problem is in how the hose is run from the machine's drain to the sink drain.

- In your first picture, the hose dips down from the machine's drain outlet, then immediately runs up hill.
- In the second picture, the hose runs over a divider panel and it looks like it's right up under the counter top above it.
- In the third picture, the hose runs back downhill to the connection to the sink drain.

I believe that the issue (as noted in [Vladimir's comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/255301/2-washing-machines-of-the-same-make-standing-water-in-both#comment512151_255301)) is that all the water that's in the "uphill" portion of the hose is running back into the machine when the drain pump turns off.

To test this theory out, you could disconnect the hose from the sink and fish it back over the raised panel. Then, *temporarily* run the hose around the front of the cabinets and through the sink cabinet door and connect it to the sink drain. In this situation, there's only one "uphill" run, right at the downstream end. When the drain pump turns off, the pressure of the water in this uphill section will be mostly offset by the pressure of the water in the downhill section where it comes out of the washer drain and should be pretty close to balancing out. There should be little to no water feeding back into the washer.

If this does solve the problem, make it a permanent solution by cutting/drilling a hole through the *bottom* of that partition wall between the cabinets and feed the hose through that hole for your long-term installation solution. This way, the hose will drop from the machine and lay along the floor/bottom of the cabinets until it makes its uphill run to the sink drain.

Comment: I think the drain pipe is to small and the washer needs to drain into a standpipe not directly connected to the drain as it needs air so it doesn't backfeed into the washer.  This would be indicated if water is backing up in the sink and flowing back into the washer. My washer manual requires the standpipe and that the discharge be above the washer.

Comment: A standpipe with an air gap is quite common in the US, @Gil on a clothes washer. However, it seems that the OP's setup (a clothes washer by the kitchen sink and draining into the sink drain) is more common in Europe and other parts of the world. Since the OP doesn't specify (and forensic analysis of the under sink bottles don't tell _me_ anything), maybe we need to find out where in the world the OP is, though the use of the word "flat" in a comment is a strong hint at UK.